# Dynamic query using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, dynamic-queries

I have an Audit model that contains EntityName and EntityIds.

I am looking for a way to create dynamic query that will retrieve the EntityRecord and related entities from this table

this is what I have so far

```
var auditRows = from a in context.Audit
                where (a.EntityName == entityName && a.EntityKey == entityKey);
```

What I wanted to get is if an Entity, say "Class" has related entity "Students". I want to craete a dynamic query that creates the where clause as

```
where (a.EntityName == entityName && a.EntityKey == entityKey) ||
      (a.EntityName == "Students" && context.Students.Where(s => s.ClassID == entityKey)
```

I found a way to get the related entities

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
var container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
var relatedEntitySets = container.EntitySets.Where(es => es.ElementType.Name == entitySet).First().ElementType.NavigationProperties
```

but I don't know how to build the query or if there is a better way to create the query.

Comment: what you actually need to do is to perform join operation

Comment: @Milo, what result you want to get is not clear to me

Comment: i.e. Class record with ID = 1, Name = "Class1" and Student record ID = 1, Name = "Student1", ClassID = 1. I want to query the Audit table to retrieve data where (EntityName = "Class" && EntityID = 1) || (EntityName = "Student" && EntityID in (SELECT Id from Student WHERE ClassID = 1). kinda like that

Comment: but if the EntityName = "School", I should not need to add the "Student" in the where clause since "School" and "Student" is not related. (in this case)

Comment: Actually Audit and Students belong to different domains. It wouldn't be wise to mix them. And actually the question is - who is a consumer of such dynamic query result? Is that really possible to work with any combination of any classes? I suppose that would be too dynamic. I'd propose something like pluggable interface which would work depending on static type of your 'audited' entity.

Comment: Do you know about `DbContext.Set(typeof(Type))`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to get rid of the WHERE and replace with ANY:

```
var students = context.GetTable<Students>();
// Repeat for other tables

where (a.EntityName == entityName && a.EntityKey == entityKey) ||
      (a.EntityName == "Students" && students.Any(s => s.ClassID == entityKey) ||
      (a.EntityName == "People" && people.Any(s => s.ClassID == entityKey) ||
      (a.EntityName == "FOO" && foo.Any(s => s.Bar == entityKey)
```

Any will generate the WHERE EXISTS() you want.

Comment: Yes this is correct. but what I wanted to create is a dynamic query for the related entities. e.g. these lines ("Students","People","FOO") . what you have is what i am currently doing, im just finding a more dynamic way.

Comment: So you are wanting it to find the entity "Students" based on the entity name and the correlating data attributes? This part is possible, and you can use reflection to get properties, etc. But I know of no way to construct a linq to entities query like this. You would need to specify them all. You could throw the entity name into a switch statement on the entity name and only have one single OR piece above to help performance though: case "Students": auditRows = auditRows.Where(a => (a.EntityName == entityName && a.EntityKey == entityKey) || (students.Any(s => s.ClassID == entityKey)));